# how to make a new column without using migration

Tags: laravel, controller, routes, laravel-5.6

I need to make new columns in a table using the controller file. for doing this task I added some migration code in the controller as follows

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

and put this inside a controller function

```
public function getColumn(Request $request)
{
    $columnName = $request->columnName;
    Schema::table('tablename', function($table)
    {
         $table->double(columnName)->nullable();
    });
}
```

here I want to put a name that was I am getting from the request, I unable to put the $columnName inside this code

Comment: $table->double(columnName,8,2)->nullable(); You forget to add in total digit and decimal place? Please provide the error message as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the columnName Variable to the function.
Probably something like this:

```
public function getColumn(Request $request)
{
    $columnName = $request->columnName;
    Schema::table('tablename', function($table) use($columnName)
    {
         $table->double($columnName)->nullable();
    });
}
```